# How do I keep track of the depth of a tree when traversing it using a stack?

Tags: algorithm, tree

If I have a tree traversal algorithm that uses a stack like this:

```
input: root
push root onto stack
while stack not empty:
    pop current node off stack
    mark current as visited
    for each of current node's successors:
        if successor not visited:
            push successor onto stack
```

Is there a simple way that I can modify this algorithm to give me the maximum depth of the tree? I can think of how to do it if i was using recursion, but I'm a bit stuck thinking of how to do it using the stack method.

Comment: @rici I think that only works for depth first search

Comment: @imran: indeed true.

Comment: @imran: now that you got me to look more closely at the pseudocode: if it is really a tree, there is no need for marking. If it is not a tree, the concept of "maximum depth" needs to be clarified.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, its a DAG, not a tree! So i do need to mark it so i dont visit anything twice.. Thanks. Pushing the depth onto the stack worked fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push the node and its depth onto the stack, and then keep track of the greatest depth you have seen so far.

```
input: root
push (root, 0) onto stack
max_depth = 0
while stack not empty:
    pop current (node, depth) off stack
    if depth > max_depth:
        max_depth = depth
    mark current as visited
    for each of current node's successors:
        if successor not visited:
            push (successor, depth+1) onto stack

return max_depth
```